# rails 4 conditions where value from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a table with a attribute called category. The category has different values 'airport', 'sights' ect.

How can i find all locations in the category 'sights' ?

i tried this:

```
@sights_markers = Location.where(:category = 'sights')
```

and this

```
@sights_markers = Location.where('category = sights')
```

and this

```
@sights_markers = Location.where('category = sights')
```

but this give me a error.

Please advise..thanks..remco

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Comment: i have read the subject..but i can't figure out how to find records with a specific value from the db.

Comment: you should escape value for use inline query `Location.where("category = 'sights'")` or `Location.where(category: 'sights')`.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple,

```
    @sights_markers = Location.where(category: 'sights')
```

Please read this at least once. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

you have make a mistake, do like this,it will work:

```
@sights_markers = Location.where(:category => 'sights')
```

or

```
@sights_markers = Location.where("category = 'sights'")
```